# How do I wire a momentary pull chain switch to a PC?

Tags: motherboard, acpi

I'm wiring a momentary pull switch to the PC. I set the Windows 10 power button action to shutdown, so pulling the chain will turn on the pc if it's off, and if it's on, pulling the chain will send a shutdown signal to WIndows. Which ports on the motherboard should I connect the pull switch to make it do what I described above?

Comment: The same 2 pins as the power switch.  You will probably have to split the wire.  Be sure you complete the circuit.  I suggest you prototype your plan.

Comment: notice: you may also need to remove/destroy the latch inside the pull chain switch if you want to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this kind of tinkering in my basement workshop.

Typically the PC Power Button is:

(a) Push ON  and then
(b) Push Longer OFF

There is a distinct timing difference in the push timing. Check that on your computer.

Now there is a pair of wires from the Motherboard to the push switch. So it is a soft switch (large majority of computers).

Tap into the pair with another pair of wires and you now have a new, added push switch capability.

You can add the pull chain to the second pair. Be aware of the longer OFF time requirement. Normally we use the Shutdown icon (Windows or Linux) to turn off a computer.

Your pull chain needs to pull ON /hold / release when you let go. Then pull OFF / hold for a longer time / release when you let go.

Here is a picture of what I wrote above.

[image]

Comment: @s3246 - have you got what you need?